# Downloaded boostrap.min.js does not work in Django template

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

Downloaded boostrap.min.js did not work in Django template but CDN boostrap.min.js did.

Here my base.html code which did not work:
[Local boostrap.min.js not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wL3L.png)
i can even open the link of javascript in developer mode of Chrome

When i change the code as below, it worked as normal :
[CDN boostrap.min.js work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzVRK.png)

ps:This is just an example, in an other app, my downloaded boostrap CSS and static files like image and fonts worked but boostrap did not

This is my setting.py:

```
"""
Django settings for website1 project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'index',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'website1.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'website1.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: While links may support what you say in your post, you should avoid links to important parts of your post, like code, for example. This is beause links tend to break eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On top of your html template

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

and then you **need to give src like this.**

```
<script src="{% static 'index/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: I have tried to put {% load staticfiles %} on top but it does not work. It seem not to be {% load staticfiles %} location

Comment: Inlcude `settings.py` in question here.

Comment: the app name is "index"

Comment: check if `bootstrap.min.js` is there at `index/static/js/bootstrap.min.js`

Comment: yep it is. I also used bootstrap.js file btw

Comment: I even copy all content of that CDN into my local javascript file but it does not work too ( but using CDN works )

Comment: Hard refresh your browser by `CTRL+Shift+Delete` and then try.

Comment: i used Ctrl+F5 to hard refresh (Chrome)

Comment: When you see source is it there?? check

Comment: in `bootstrap.min.js` , it have codes. I download and use compiled CSS and JS btw.

Comment: Thank for your help. After a long while searching, i found out that bootstrap 4 does not support affix. So i created one and it works !

Comment: @Shay, Thanks for letting me know this. Thanks a lot.